# Master page issue in asp.net after publishing

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, asp.net-3.5, publishing

I am facing a unique issue with my application.

In my master page, I have few CSS scripts tag and some coding to display some text on the Master page and everything is working fine.

but when I am publishing the same website, on same server and opening it on the same browser, I can see that all the CSS which I have written on the Master Page is vanished.

I have no idea what happened...

Comment: What do you mean with vanished? Is the link to your .css file broken? Are you referencing it right from the base of your web application? That's what I'd guess happend.

Comment: Whats the URL of the broekn website (if it is live?)?

Comment: <div style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:42px; color:White;" visible="true">
 MY MASTER PAGE TEXT
 </div>

Comment: I have created a new DIV in the Master page, the text under this is visible when I am running the application from Visual studio but not after pubslihing it. I am using IE7 everytime

Comment: @Dave: It's an intranet site.

Comment: Strange but true.. When I placed this code inside the div <label title="add"></label> I can see the text. Can anyone please now help me out ?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Are you using external CSS files? If so, when you publish and view your page, and then view source - are the <link > tags still there? What if you view source on your local, are the <link > tags there? Is this inline CSS you're talking about? Perhaps it's being overridden by linked CSS files?. I think we need some source and examples of local vs prod

Comment: @Prescott Thanks for your assistance. But I am publishing on the same server on which I am developing the application. There is no local and prod server, I am developing the website on production server.

Comment: @Prescott I can see that on the page, CSS is also not same as it look while opening on Visual studio. I am loading my CSS from the CSS file, via link. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post what your code looks like in VS and what it looks like on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you provided indicates the text is white. White text on a white background isn't the problem, is it?

We could help you better if you could provide a more complete code sample.

Comment: Background color is brown. but the same text is visible when I am running my website from VS2008 but not visible after publishing.

Comment: You have to show more of your source code because that is where the problem lies.